# incompatibility of nohyperref and xifthen in specific situations

Tags: hyperref, compilation-error

The following MWE compiles with `hyperref` but not with `nohyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{nohyperref} %with hyperref it compiles perfectly wihtout warnings
\newcommand{\f}[1]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{f}{f(#1)}
}
\newcommand{\D}{\hyperref[eq:D]{\normalcolor D}}

\begin{document}   
\begin{equation}\label{eq:D}
\f{\D}  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When I replce `\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}` by `\ifblank{#1}` it compiles at least but still with an error.

Comment: ah, \hyperref is not robust in nohyperref. I can change that, but your test is rather odd. It is dangerous to pass arbitrary content to \ifthenelse.

Comment: I guess `\ifblank{#1}` is less odd for the purpose of checking if an argument is blank?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer When you say that you can change that, you mean that you can update the `nohyperref` package?

Comment: yes I can update nohyperref.

Comment: try as a work-around \RenewDocumentCommand\hyperref{om}{#2}.

Comment: surprisonly ` \RenewDocumentCommand\hyperref{om}{#2}` does not work with \ifblank, while it works with \ifthenelse

Comment: I don't know what you mean. works fine for me with etoolbox and \ifblank

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not using the best approach to the problem. Can you give a more “real-world” example?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: etoolbox was the solution. etoolbox is apparantly automaitcally loaded for hyperref but not for nohyperref

Comment: With a recent LaTeX, where expl3/LaTeX 3 is integrated into LaTe 2e, there is `\tl_if_blank:nTF`. Instead of using `\ifthenelse` you can do `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new_eq:NN \CheckWhetherBlank \tl_if_blank:nTF \ExplSyntaxOff` and `\newcommand{\f}[1]{f\CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{}{(#1)}}`.

Comment: the next hyperref version will make the command robust (protected).

Answer (score 3):

I never use the package **nohyperref**.

For toggling between turning on/off hyperlinks with the hyperref package I have TeX do globally what usually is done only within **hyperref**'s environment `NoHyper`; bookmarks need to be taken care of as well:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% For turning off hyperlinks activate,                                               %
%% for turning on hyperlinks turn into a comment                                      %                             
%% the following line:                                                                %
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}\newcommand\ProbablySwitchOffHyperlinks{\NoHyper}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\providecommand\ProbablySwitchOffHyperlinks{}%
\ProbablySwitchOffHyperlinks
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\f}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{f}{f(#1)}}
\newcommand{\D}{\hyperref[eq:D]{\normalcolor D}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{bla}
\section{blu}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:D}
\f{\D}  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this soolution does not work for journals that forbid hyperref. Some of them explicitly check for `\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}`

Comment: @Jakob Probably patching `\@ifpackageloaded` to check whether the argument is the string "hyperref" and in this case deliver the "false"-branch and otherwise do the original `\@ifpackageloaded`-routine works out. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm under the impression that you're using the wrong tool (I'm referring to `\ifthenelse`). Anyway, make `\hyperref` robust and you'll be on your way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{nohyperref} %with hyperref it compiles perfectly wihtout warnings

\MakeRobust{\hyperref}

\newcommand{\f}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{f}{f(#1)}%
}
\newcommand{\D}{\hyperref[eq:D]{\normalcolor D}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:D}
\f{\D}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The test `\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}...` in the ⟨replacement text⟩ of the definition of the macro `\f` seems to be intended to be an approximation of a test for whether the argument represented by the parameter `#1` consists of tokens, the processing of which results in an area being created in the output file (.pdf-file or .dvi-file) that can be made into a clickable hyperlink.

---

If you do `\DeclareRobustCommand{\D}` instead of `\newcommand{\D}`, then your code compiles without error messages:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{nohyperref} %with hyperref it compiles perfectly wihtout warnings
\newcommand{\f}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{f}{f(#1)}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\D}{\hyperref[eq:D]{\normalcolor D}}

\begin{document}   
\begin{equation}\label{eq:D}
\f{\D}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:empty}
\f{}  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This solution works without loading other packages and without patching existing macros.

This solution should also work for [journals that forbid hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/705312/incompatibility-of-nohyperref-and-xifthen-in-specific-situations/705367#comment1753431_705322). ;-)

---

---

I think turning a component of an equation into a hyperlink leading to the number of that same equation might not resemble a real life scenario but your example is intended to exhibit problems related to the need of having behavior of commands vary depending on the situation in which they are carried out. (While in the situation of evaluating the `\ifthenelse`-test the command `\hyperref` is to behave in a way which differs from its behavior when in the situation of typesetting and creating hyperlinks within the output file (.dvi-file/.pdf-file).)

The test `\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}...` in the ⟨replacement text⟩ of the definition of the macro `\f` seems to be intended to be an approximation  of a test for whether the argument represented by the parameter `#1` consists of tokens, the processing of which results in an area being created in the output file (.pdf-file or .dvi-file) that can be made into a clickable hyperlink.

The command `\ifthenelse` beneath other things within a local scope does `\let\equal\TE@equal` while evaluating its test-argument.
This fact can be used for forking depending on whether currently in the situation of evaluating the test-argument of an instance of the macro `\ifthenelse` and in this case omitting/removing tokens that cannot be carried out/are not needed in this case:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen, xcolor}
\usepackage{nohyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CheckWhetherCurrentlyEvaluatingIfthenelseTest{%
  \ifx\equal\TE@equal\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
\newcommand{\D}{%
  \CheckWhetherCurrentlyEvaluatingIfthenelseTest{\@firstofone}{\hyperref[eq:D]}%
  {\CheckWhetherCurrentlyEvaluatingIfthenelseTest{}{\normalcolor}D}%
}%
\makeatother

\newcommand{\f}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{f}{f(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\color{blue}
\tableofcontents
\section{bla}
\section{blu}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:D}
\f{\D}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:empty}
\f{}  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This example is somewhat overkill. But it illustrates how expandable commands could be designed to do different things depending on the situations in which they are expanded/carried out.
Unfortunately, there is no "situation management" in LaTeX where you could reliably query at any time what kind of situation LaTeX is currently in, let alone extend the repertoire of situation types and the repertoire of situation-dependent behaviors of a command.